# How to report related findings in a pentest report

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, vulnerability-assessment

I am running a pentest on a web application, and I detected a vulnerability but I am not sure how to report it. I am confused if I should split it or document it as 1 finding. I will explain below.

So the finding is, a JWT token with large TTL value(finding 1 ) that is being saved in the browser local storage(finding 2), and and XSS script in one of the urls (finding 3).
The combination of these 3 findings helped me do an exploit, the exploit requires the user to click on a link and sign in, and then the JWT Token of the user is sent to a remote server.

If I want to report all this, what is the best approach? Shall I report 3 findings + 1 poc?
Or 1 finding and 1 poc? or ?
And is the poc considered a finding here or it is just an exploit of the vulnerabilities detected?

Answer (score 3):

My advise is to make three findings:

- XSS: High risk, include the PoC here. The details of the other issues are naturally included because you have to write reproduction steps.
- JWT token with large TTL: Low risk. Not a big deal in itself.
- JWT token in local storage: Low risk. Not a big deal in itself.

The main reason for making three findings is that the fix for one doesn't fix the rest. If you combine them, retesting becomes terrible. If they accept the risk of one of the three, the finding will always be "partially fixed" even though they mitigated the main issue.

In the management summary and the findings meeting you can note that with some quick wins they can mitigate the risk of the XSS vulnerability by fixing the other two. However, because a pentest is a snapshot in time, fixing the other vulnerabilities doesn't change the risk in the report.